# Canonical method of modifying (add/delete code) a binary executable programmatically?

Tags: security, gcc, x86, executable, binaryfiles

I've always had a great interest in computer security and after reading:

*Surreptitious Software: Obfuscation, Watermarking, and Tamperproofing for Software Protection*

-I'd like to implement some of these algorithms, which assume that you are able to modify an executable at the binary level.

Using a HEX editor, I have accomplished to insert a simple checksum algorithm for tamper-proofing protection of a code region. However, this technique is not feasible in practice, so I'm looking for ways of automating this.

Are there any well-known frameworks or techniques that takes an executable as input and allow the programmer to work with the code in a programatically way? If not, what are my options?

By programatically, I mean, parse it into, e.g., a tree-like structure that can be written back out as a new (modified) executable.

Thank you for your time and interest.

Comment: This is in general fairly difficult as much of the information you need for this purpose is lost by the time your program is compiled and linked. For example, there isn't even a way to find out where functions or variables begin in the code.